# Expo web-app not asking for camera permission on iOS and Android browsers

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, expo

Within my Expo project I'm using expo-camera. Both on Android and iOS the camera asks permission before opening it.

But when I try to open the web version of my project on a mobile device browser, the camera access is denied directly without asking.  I tried this on an iPhone 12 and a Samsung Galaxy S20. But both didn't ask permission.

Within my code I use the following line to ask for permission:

```js
 const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null)

 useEffect(() => {
    ;(async () => {
      const { status } = await Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync()
      setHasPermission(status === 'granted')
    })()
  }, [])
```

This is how I call the camera component from `expo-camera`

```js
import { Camera, CameraType } from 'expo-camera'

return (
      <Camera ref={ref => set_camera(ref)} type={type} style={{ flex: 1 }}/>
)
```

How can I make a mobile browser also ask for camera permission and prevent it from denying directly?

Answer (score 0):

If you run on a phone (web browser), over WIFI, be sure to use HTTPS